# Add HTTPS url property to Google Search Console through API

Tags: curl, google, google-webmaster-tools

I had a look on this page to see how to add a website https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sitemaps/submit

This code works :

`curl --request PUT \ 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http://www.MY_URL.com' \ --header 'Content-length: 0' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' \ --header 'Accept: application/json' \ --compressed`

But this code with HTTPS does not work :

`curl --request PUT \ 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https://www.MY_URL.com' \ --header 'Content-length: 0' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' \ --header 'Accept: application/json' \ --compressed`

So how to add an HTTPS url to Google Search Console programmaticaly ?

Thanks for your advice

L.